SQLModel (SQLAlchemy and pydantic) Invalid Reference
Hi everyone Can someone help me, I tried to fix this error, looking in the web and with chatgpt but I can reach any solution.
I'm trying to modelate a database tables in sqlalchemy, using SQLModel but it thows me this error:
psycopg.errors.UndefinedTable: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "rel_level_index"
LINE 2: ...rel_rod_column ON rel_rod_column.id_start_level = rel_level_...
^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "rel_level_index_1".
These are my models:
class RelRodColumn(SQLModel, table=True):
    """Stores the number of rods in each column and the levels each rod will occupy
id_column: int -> Foreign key of the column
id_rod: int -> Foreign key of the rod
id_start_level: int -> Level in which rod start
id_end_level: int -> Level in which rod end
amount: int -> Rods amount, how many rods will have each column"""
    __tablename__ = "rel_rod_column"

    class Config:
        """Configuration to validate class model before create object"""
        validate_assignment: bool = True

    id_column: Optional[int] = Field(foreign_key="columns.id", nullable=False, primary_key=True,
                                     gt=0, lt=2_147_483_647)
    id_rod: Optional[int] = Field(foreign_key="rods.id", nullable=False, primary_key=True,
                                  gt=0, lt=2_147_483_647)
    id_start_level: Optional[int] = Field(foreign_key="rel_level_index.id", nullable=False, primary_key=True,
                                          gt=0, lt=2_147_483_647)
    id_end_level: Optional[int] = Field(foreign_key="rel_level_index.id", nullable=False, primary_key=True,
                                        gt=0, lt=2_147_483_647)
    amount: int = Field(nullable=False, gt=0, lt=32_767)

    rel_column: "Column" = Relationship(back_populates="rel_column__rel_rod_column",
                                        sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"})
    rel_rod: "Rod" = Relationship(back_populates="rel_rod__rel_rod_column",
                                  sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"})
    rel_start_level: "RelLevelIndex" = Relationship(back_populates="rel_start_level__rel_rod_column",
                                                    sa_relationship_kwargs={
                                                        "lazy": "selectin",
                                                        "foreign_keys": "RelRodColumn.id_start_level",
                                                    })
    rel_end_level: "RelLevelIndex" = Relationship(back_populates="rel_end_level__rel_rod_column",
                                                  sa_relationship_kwargs={
                                                      "lazy": "selectin",
                                                      "foreign_keys": "RelRodColumn.id_end_level"
                                                  })

class RelLevelIndex(BaseModel, table=True):  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Store the order of the levels. Suppose the next levels are stored,
L-1, L2, S-2, S-1, PB and you do not know which one is first,

    Level: S-2 Index: 1 means that is the first level in the building
    Level: S-1 Index: 2 means that is the second level in the building
    Level: L-2 Index: 3 means that is the third level in the building
    Level: L-1 Index: 4 means that is the fourth level in the building
    Level: PB Index: 5 means that is the fifth level in the building
    And go on.

id: int -> Primary key, ID generated automatically

id_level: int -> ID of the level stored in the levels table

index: int -> Order of the level, e.g, firme -> index:1, cimento ->
index:2, l1 -> index:3, l2 -> index:4
    """
    __tablename__ = "rel_level_index"

    id_level: Optional[int] = Field(foreign_key="levels.id", nullable=False,
                                    gt=0, lt=2_147_483_647)
    index: int = Field(nullable=False, ge=-32_768, lt=32_767)

    rel_level__rel_level_index: "Level" = Relationship(back_populates="rel_index__rel_level_index",
                                                       sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"})
    rel_column__rel_column_level: "RelColumnLevel" = Relationship(back_populates="rel_level_index",
                                                                  sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"})

    rel_start_level__rel_rod_column: RelRodColumn = Relationship(
        back_populates="rel_start_level",
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "secondary": "rel_rod_column",
            "primaryjoin": "RelLevelIndex.id == foreign(RelRodColumn.id_start_level)",
            "secondaryjoin": "RelRodColumn.id_start_level == foreign(RelLevelIndex.id)"
        }
    )
    rel_end_level__rel_rod_column: RelRodColumn = Relationship(
        back_populates="rel_end_level",
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "secondary": "rel_rod_column",
            "primaryjoin": "RelLevelIndex.id == foreign(RelRodColumn.id_end_level)",
            "secondaryjoin": "RelRodColumn.id_end_level == foreign(RelLevelIndex.id)",
        }
    )

Putting an aliased like
start_level__rel_rod_column = aliased(RelRodColum)
'lazy': 'selectin',
"secondary": "rel_rod_column",
"primaryjoin": "RelLevelIndex.id == foreign(start_level__rel_rod_column.id_start_level)",
"secondaryjoin": "start_level__rel_rod_column.id_start_level == foreign(RelLevelIndex.id)"
Do you have any idea of what can I do? How to fix my model?
